# Fine tuning oracle query with pipelined function

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex, database-performance, pipelined-function

I have a query (that powers an Oracle Application Express Report) that I was told by our users was executing "slowly" or at an unacceptable speed (wasn't given an actual load time for the page and the query is the only thing on the page).

The query involves many tables and actually references a pipelined function which identifies the currently logged-in users to our website and returns a custom "table" of records they have permission to based upon a custom security scheme we have.

My main question is around Oracle's caching of queries and how they could be affected by our setup.

When I took the query out of the webpage and ran it in Sql Developer (and manually specified a user ID to simulate a logged-in user to the website), the performance went from 71 seconds to 19 seconds to .5 seconds.  Clearly, Oracle is utilizing its caching mechanism to make subsequent runs faster.

How is this affected by?:

1. The fact that different users will get different tables from the
   pipe-lined function (all the same columns, just different number of
   rows and the values in the rows).  Does the pipe-lining prevent
   caching from working?  Am I only seeing caching because I'm running
   a very isolated test?
2. Further more - is caching easily influenced by the number of people using the system?  I'm not sure how "**much**" can get cached.  Therefore, if we have 50 concurrent users that are accessing different parts of the website that are loading different queries all day long, is it likely that oracle won't be able to cache many/any of them because it is constantly seeing different request for queries?

Sorry my question isn't very technical.

I'm a developer who has been asked to help out in this seemingly DBA question.

Also, this is complicated because I can't really determine what the actual load times are since our users don't report that level of detail.

Any thoughts on:

- how I can determine if this query is actually slow?
- what the average processing time would be?
- and how to proceed with fine tuning if it is a problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't sound like this has anything to do with APEX, pipelined table functions, or query caching.  It sounds like you are describing the effects of plain old data caching (most likely at the database level but potentially at the operating system and disk subsystem layers).

As a very basic overview, data is stored in rows, rows are stored in blocks (most commonly 8 kb in size), blocks are stored in extents (generally a few MB in size), and extents roll up to segments (i.e. a table).  Oracle maintains a buffer cache where the most recently accessed blocks are stored.  When you run a query, Oracle figures out which blocks it needs to read in order to get your data (this is the query plan).  It then looks to see whether those blocks are in the buffer cache or whether they have to be read from disk.  Obviously, reading a block from cache is much more efficient than reading it off the disk since RAM is much faster than disk.  If you run the same query with the same set of bind variable values multiple times in a row, you'll be accessing the same set of blocks each time but more and more of the blocks you care about are going to be in the cache.  So you'd generally expect that the second and third time that you call the query, you'll see faster performance.

If you run the query with a different set of bind variable values, if the second set of bind variable values causes Oracle to access many of the same blocks, those executions will benefit from the data the prior test cached.  Otherwise, you'd be back to square 1 potentially reading all the data you need off disk.  Most likely, you'll see some combination of the two.

Remember as well that it is not just Oracle that is caching data.  Frequently, the operating system will be caching the most active pieces of the underlying Oracle data files.  And the I/O subsystem will be caching the most recently accessed data as well.  So even if Oracle thinks that it needs to go out to fetch a block because it is not in the database's buffer cache, the file system or the I/O subsystem may have cached that data so it may not require an actual physical read off of disk.  These other caches behave similarly where running the same query multiple times in a row is likely to cause the cache to be "warm" and improve the performance of the later runs.

Comment: thanks for the detailed breakdown!  from what you explained, i agree it is likely data caching.  your 3rd paragraph describes what i am most likely seeing.  the same query ran many times with different bind values substituted-in each time.  each run of the pipelined function "hits" the same tables, but just returns a smaller or larger subset of the data based upon who you are.  so with that being said, could you recommend how i can further investigate how to address this?  look into learning explain plans?  i just want to ensure that my users don't experience the 70 second runtimes like i did!

Comment: @user3249281 - It's hard to make really general performance tuning suggestions that are particularly useful-- there are a lot of "it depends".  Step one is to figure out what is consuming the time (or, if we believe that the majority of the time is spent doing I/O, what is causing the majority of the logical I/O).  Looking at the query plan and the execution statistics will likely help here.  You might trace the session as well but the query plan is probably the easier starting point.